# Automatically change excel cell value depending on current Month

Tags: excel, formulas

Stock analysis Dashboard. I need to compare the stock from today vs the previous 6 months.

My stock data

Cell A1:R1 - month data example Cell A1= June 2017, B1=  7/2017 ....till R1= December 2018.

Cell A2:R2 Stock numbers data example A2=23, B2=25,........till R2=50.

IF I want to see the stock today month which is July 2018= M1 vs six months February 2018 H2 and the stock level calculation will which is `M2=26 - H2= 30 =-4`.

But instead of entering formula every time I need to be updated every month based on the today month?

Any tips on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also miss a date...

If you use today()  function to identify today's date you can use:

=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),$A$1:$S$2,2)-HLOOKUP(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-5,1),$A$1:$S$2,2)

If you need a cell with a specific date, replace today() formula with that cell.

[image: Excel printscreen]

Comment: I like this better than using an array formula.  Are you assuming that the values in A1:R1 are all dates that fall on the first of the month?  If not, how did you populate those values?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Works perfectly fine !

Answer (score 0):

I find the question a bit confusing.  If A1 is June 2017, I am missing a month if R1 is December 2018 and July 2017 is in M1.  Also, even though you said 6 months, I am assuming that you want 5 months so that July compares to February.
This response assumes that A1 is wrong but R1 and M1 (and B1 through R1 are accurate) and that the values in A1 through R1 are actually an Excel date that is formatted as m/yyyy (as opposed to some text representation of a date).

This formula is further complicated since I do not know what day is used in the date representation in A1 through R1, hence I am adapting both that date and the current date to be a fixed day of the month (I chose the first day of the month in my formula).

Here is the formula that computes the -4 assuming M1 is 7/2018, M2 is 26, H1 is 2/2018, H2 is 30 and we want to compare column M to column H since today is in July and we want to compare July to February (5 months difference):

```
=INDIRECT("R2C"&MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0),FALSE)-INDIRECT("R2C"&MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0)-5,FALSE)
```

This is an array function so it needs to be entered with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

The way it works is that it computes from today's date, the date value equal to the first day of this month.  Then it compares that against the range A1:R1 with each of those dates likewise moved to the first of the month.  This gives us the column to use for "this month" and using the same computation but subtracting 5 gives us the column to use for "six months ago."  Out of sheer laziness I used these values in an indirect cell reference to pull the Row 2 values for "this month" and "six months ago" and subtracted the latter from the former (i.e., "this month" - "six months ago").

In other words, this part of the formula gives me the column of the current month:

```
MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0)
```

and this part gives me the column of the month six months ago (as defined in the original post):

```
MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0)-5
```

As I indicated, this may not be what you wanted, but this is what I thought you were asking.

---

### Alternate version using INDEX function

```
=INDEX(A2:R2,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0))-INDEX(A2:R2,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),DATE(YEAR(A1:R1),MONTH(A1:R1),1),0)-5)
```

The above would also be entered as an array formula.

Comment: Indeed a miscalculation cell vs the dates ,  Thank you for the input, it works fine.

Comment: =INDEX('Product analysis'!$AN2:$BK2,MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,'Product analysis'!$AN$1:$BK$1,0))-OFFSET(INDEX('Product analysis'!$AN2:$BK2,MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,'Product analysis'!$AN$1:$BK$1,0)),0,-E$1,1,1)